# Attach #ajax to submit button created in hook_form_alter with #markup

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I created a custom submit button for the user-login form using #markup because I couldn't alter submit button html to resemble what I needed. The second custom submit button with the needed html is added with:

```
$form['submit2'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<p class="submit"><button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-large"></i></button></p>');
```

I then added a "hideme" class to the orginal button with `$form['actions']['submit']` `['#attributes']` (deleting it stopped the other submit from working).

So far so good. But now I would like to validate the login form using AJAX. Only if I add the `#ajax` key to `$form['submit2']`, the callback is never called. This only seems to work with regular form items.

Is it possible to trigger an Ajax callback on a `#markup` element (in `hook_form_alter`)? I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, since the #ajax attribute is not used for the [markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup) item. You can use an [image_button](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#image_button) form element.

If the image_button form element doesn't render as you want and it is not possible to alter it the way you want, you need to implement a new form element with [`hook_element_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7), using the definition of the image_button form element as guide.

```
  $types['image_button'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE,
    '#button_type' => 'submit',
    '#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE,
    '#limit_validation_errors' => FALSE,
    '#process' => array('ajax_process_form'),
    '#return_value' => TRUE,
    '#has_garbage_value' => TRUE,
    '#src' => NULL,
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('image_button'),
  );
```

The theme function that renders that form element is [theme_image_button()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_image_button/7). Changing the value of #theme_wrappers, you can alter the way your form element is rendered.
Keep in mind that theme wrappers, as any other theme functions, need to be declared with [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).

Comment: Defining a new form element with custom theme_wrapper turned out to be the way to go. As a pointer for those trying the same, in addition to defining the new element with hook_element_info, you also need to register your custom theme_wrapper with hook_theme. The custom wrapper allowed me to output the submit button exactly as I wanted it.